# Wordpress: Wp nav menu have to be called twice to work correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have below code. The bug seems to be when I take out the first block of code of wp_nav_menu, the html will be messed. But if I leave it like below code, it create double same functon call which is redundant. Can anyone help? Thank you

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <?php wp_body_open(); ?>
    <div id="page" class="site" style="display: flex; flex-direction:column; min-height:100vh">
        <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#primary"><?php esc_html_e('Skip to content', 'sdsd'); ?></a>
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu(
            [
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ]
        );
        ?>
        <header class="header_area">
            <div class="main_header_area animated sticky">
                <div class="container">
                    <nav id="navigation1" class="navigation">
                        <div class="nav-header">
                            <!-- <a class="nav-brand" href="#"></a> -->
                            <a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>">
                                <div class="nav-logo">
                                    <?php
                                    $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod('custom_logo');
                                    $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom_logo_id, 'full');
                                    if (has_custom_logo()) {
                                        echo '<img src="' . esc_url($logo[0]) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo('name') . '">';
                                    } else {
                                        echo '<h1>' . get_bloginfo('name') . '</h1>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="nav-toggle"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-search">
                            <div class="nav-search-button"><i class="nav-search-icon"></i></div>
                            <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url() ?>">
                                <div class="nav-search-inner">
                                    <input type="search" name="s" placeholder="Search..." value="<?php get_search_query() ?>" />
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-menus-wrapper">
                            <?php
                            wp_nav_menu([
                                'container' => "",
                                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                                'menu_class' => 'nav-menu align-to-right',
                                'walker' => new My_Walker(),
                            ]);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Answer (score -1):

writing function twice is not recommended for creating menu.i run same code on twenty-twenty theme and it works fine,

can you screenshot or share the link so it could help better understand whats the issue is.

Comment: Hi @asma_dev, I have found out the solution from this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337744/wp-nav-menu-not-working-correctly-in-my-underscores-theme

Answer (score -1):

for you who are in the same boat, I've found this and I realized that one of my function which uses a filter hook wp_nav_menu_items had a problem. Please refer to this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337744/wp-nav-menu-not-working-correctly-in-my-underscores-theme